# My Python program made with pyinstaller not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, exe

I made a python executable program with pyinstaller --onefile mode.

On my computer, It works properly.

But when I move it to another one, It doesn't work.

When I start the program, It shows nothing. In the task manager, the program process just show up and disappears in few seconds.

So I tried to run it in CMD with permission.

[CMD when I tried to execute exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAcpu.png)

It stays in this state for about 5 minutes and then nothing.

[CMD After 5 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCj3i.png)

I already turned off anti virus and I installed Python on that computer.

Please help me. What is wrong?

**so summary:**

1. I made a exe with pyinstaller
2. It works well on my computer
3. It doesn't work on another computer
4. with anti-virus offed
5. the CMD is still that state while I finished writing. Help me..!

Comment: Please post the error text, not an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.